# Python: cannot assign value to element, when it is the output of reduce function

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, reduce

I am having trouble understanding why there is a problem with a python2 program I'm working on.

The following runs fine:

```
from functools import reduce

C=[[[0],[1]],[[2],[3]]]

print C[0][0], C[0][1]
print C[1][0], C[1][1]

print "Element with indices 1,1:", reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C)

reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C).append(4)
print C[0][0], C[0][1]
print C[1][0], C[1][1]
```

It outputs:

```
[0] [1]
[2] [3]
Element with indices 1,1: [3]
[0] [1]
[2] [3, 4]
```

However, if I add the following lines:

```
reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C)=[4]
```

I get the error:

```
    reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C)=[4]
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I am a little confused here. In the first case, I was able to alter the element of the list that `reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C)` is pointing to, using *append*. But in the second case, I cannot change its value. I feel I'm missing something basic here. Can somebody please explain what is the difference between those two cases?

Comment: what do you think `reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C)=[4] ` is going to do?

Comment: I made sure my question was detailed and clear, and I provided a minimal working example. Two downvotes for what is essentially lack of understanding?! Oh well.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I thought it would assign [4] to C[1][1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning doesn't modify a pre-existing value. It takes a new value and assigns it to a target. For example:

```
x = y = [1]
x = [2]       #doesn't change y
```

For that reason, you can't assign into the result of a function call: It doesn't make sense to do so because there is nothing that can be reassigned.

To change the contents of a list without reassigning it, use `x[:] = [2]`. This is slice-assignment, which is different from normal assignment in that it modifies the content of the list without reassigning the list itself. In the example above, this would modify both `x` and `y` because they are still referring to the same list.

In your code, you would need:

```
reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C)[:] = [4]
                                   ^^^
```

to modify the list returned by `reduce`:

```
>>> C=[[[0],[1]],[[2],[3]]]
>>> reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C)[:] = [4]
>>> C
[[[0], [1]], [[2], [4]]]
```

Comment: This is a very good answer...I did not know that the splice operator could turn an expression into a valid left-hand side for an assignment statement...+1

Comment: `reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [1,1], C)[1:] = [4]` would be the same as the append.

Comment: Indeed, one could further abstract `append` by using `reduce(lambda l, i: l[i], [x, y], C)[len(C[x][y]):] = [4]`